# MYSQL: update table with values from another related table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have two MySQL tables, here's how they are structured:

```
table foo(
 foo_id varchar(32),
 field1 varchar(32),
 field2 varchar(32),
 bar_id varchar(32) 
);

table bar(
  bar_id varchar(32),
  field1 varchar(32),
  field2 varchar(32)
);
```

I would like to update the `foo` table to have the same values for `field1` and `field2` as the `bar` table. I've tried the following two queries, both of which run without error, but don't get me the results I want:

```
UPDATE foo LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.bar_id = bar.bar_id 
SET foo.field1 = bar.field1 AND foo.field2 = bar.field2;
```

also

```
UPDATE foo,bar SET foo.field1 = bar.field1 
AND foo.field2 = bar.field2 WHERE foo.bar_id = bar.bar_id
```

but neither work. what am I missing here?

Comment: i find no wrong in your queries. i suggest to use select statement and find the rows which will be updated by above statment. like: `select foo.*, bar.* from foo LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.bar_id = bar.bar_id 
SET foo.field1 = bar.field1 AND foo.field2 = bar.field2;`

Comment: @KoolKabin in MySQL you can't both select from and update a table in the same query

Comment: well it was not for doing select from and update in same query. it was doing select in one statement and checking the resultset and if the resultset is fine then execute the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you have problems with `AND`; should be comma instead. This way I think you are updating `foo.field1` to become `(bar.field1 AND foo.field2 = bar.field2)` (logical conjunction between non-zeroness of `bar.field1` and equality of `field2`-s), and I'm pretty sure that's not what you meant. Didn't test though; might be wrong.

Comment: you're right, that was the problem. Though I find it odd that that wasn't a syntax error of somesort in MySQL. I'm assuming it thought I meant SET foo.field1 = (bar.field1 AND foo.field2 = bar.field2) and set the value to a boolean

Comment: MySQL has fairly permissive implicit casting, and `=` works for both assignment and comparison in SQL, so... no, no error. :)